# Constante que se define con un tipo de error, ENVIRONMENT

Tags: php

Me he encontrado esta clase para conectar mediante PDO en internet y analizándola hay algo que no entiendo. Cuando, en el condicional, pregunta si está definida la constante 'environment' y si es igual a 'development' ¿se refiere a una constante que debe haber sido definida por el programador anteriormente?¿o se refiere a una constante predefinida en php que desconozco? porque he buscado por los otros archivos y no he encontrado nada, y buscando en el manual y en internet tampoco

Lo curioso es que parece definirse l constante con un tipo de error...

A ver si sabéis algo acerca de esto

Gracias!

```
class DbConnect {
    private $conn;

    function __construct() {        
    } 

    function connect() {
        include_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/Config.php';

        try {
            $this->conn = new PDO('mysql:host=' .
                            DB_HOST.';dbname='.
                            DB_NAME.';charset=utf8', 
                            DB_USERNAME, 
                            DB_PASSWORD);

            $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


            return $this->conn;

        } catch(PDOException $ex) {

            // if the environment is development, show error details, otherwise show generic message
            if ( (defined('ENVIRONMENT')) && (ENVIRONMENT == 'development') ) {
                echo 'An error occured connecting to the database! Details: ' . $ex->getMessage();
            } else {
                echo 'An error occured connecting to the database!'. $ex->getMessage();
            }
            exit;
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cada extensión puede definir sus propias constantes, y existe la buena práctica de colocarles un prefijo relacionado con la extensión. Definitivamente no es una constante de núcleo, las cuales por lo regular tienen el prefijo PHP_.

A reserva de que use algún framework y revises la documentación es claro que el propósito -hasta donde podemos ver- es simplemente mostrar información al desarrollador.

Al programar en equipo surge la necesidad de Operaciones de Desarrollo (DevOps) en donde solemos tener varios ambientes (computadoras y/o servidores) denominados según la etapa de desarrollo o madurez del código, por mencionar algunos:

- Desarrollo (DEV)
- Pruebas o Control de Calidad (TST, QA)
- Pruebas de Aceptación usuario (UAT)
- Pruebas de desplegado ó Staging (STG)
- Producción (PROD)

Dependiendo de las necesidades del proyecto tendrás dos o más, y el código se irá moviendo unidireccionalmente desde el primero al último.

La constante misteriosa es para definir ese ambiente, de tal manera que no se debería definir en el ambiente Productivo para no mostrar información que puede ser útil a un desarrollador -o hacker- pero muy inconveniente a un usuario terrenal. Es decir, puedes asignar valor a la constante a `development` en cualquier ambiente de desarrollo que tú controles, pero cuida que bajo ninguna circunstancia ese valor llegue al ambiente Productivo, en donde seguramente tendrá otro valor o ninguno.

Comment: A ver si lo he entendido bien. Esa constante fue creada para obtener una información en uno de los "ambientes" de pruebas o desarrollo. Pero para producción se eliminó. Hasta ahí bien pero, en realidad está obteniendo la misma información se cumpla o no el condicional. Si no me confundo, en este caso, no sería de mucha utilidad diferenciar el ambiente de trabajo ¿verdad?

Comment: Es correcto, la cuestión es que el comentario al código no concuerda con el mismo y no debería ser así.

Comment: Muchas Gracias @Sal!